# "train" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable) [Ln 124, Col 13]

Tags: python, training-data, custom-training, generative-art

I have defined my "train" via def function, although lines PREVIOUS my def seems to not have any issues. However line that mentions "train" last gives an error of undefined variable. Here is my code, this is not the full code and I am working in VS Code environment I will just add the folder where my issue is:

PS: I have tried some ways to fix the issue:
to define "train" as a global variable in `def train(args):[ln 65]`
also
`train_dataloader = get_data(args, train=True) validation_dataloader = get_data(args, train=False)`

to rearrange the code and where "train" is

> import os
> import copy
> import numpy as np
> import torch
> import torch.nn as nn
> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
> from torch import optim
> from tqdm import tqdm
> from utils import *
> from modules import UNet_conditional, EMA
> import logging
> from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
> from torch_geometric.data import DataLoader
> from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
>
> logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(messages)s", level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%I:%M:%S")
>
> class Diffusion:
> def **init**(self, noise_steps=1000, beta_start=1e-4, beta_end=0.82, img_size=64, device="cuda"):
> self.noise_steps = noise_steps
> self.beta_start = beta_start
> self.beta_end = beta_end
> self.img_size = img_size
> self.device = device
>
> self.beta = self.prepare_noise_schedule().to(device)
> self.alpha = 1. - self.beta
> self.alpha_hat = torch.cumprod(self.alpha, dim=0)
>
> def prepare_noise_schedule(self):
> return torch.linspace(self.beta_start, self.beta_end, self.noise_steps)
>
> def noise_images(self, x, t):
> sqrt_alpha_hat = torch.sqrt(self.alpha_hat[t])[:, None, None, None]
> torch.randn_like(x)
> return sqrt_alpha_hat * x + sqrt_alpha_hat * Ɛ, Ɛ
>
> def sample_timesteps(self, n):
> return torch.randint(low=1, high=self.noise_steps, size=(n,))
>
> def sample(self, model, n, labels, cfg_scale=3):
> logging.info(f"Sampling {n} new images....")
> model.eval()
> with torch.no_grad():
> x = torch.randn((n, 3, self.img_size, self.img_size)).to(self.device)
> for i in tqdm(reversed(range(1, self.noise_steps)), position=0):
> t = (torch.ones(n) * i).long().to(self.device)
> predicted_noise = model(x, t, labels)
> if cfg_scale > 0:
> uncond_predicted_noise = model(x, t, None)
> predicted_noise = torch.lerp(uncond_predicted_noise, predicted_noise, cfg_scale)
> alpha = self.alpha[t][:, None, None, None]
> alpha_hat = self.alpha_hat[t][:, None, None, None]
> beta = self.beta[t][:, None, None, None]
> if i > 1:
> noise = torch.randn_like(x)
> else:
> noise = torch.zeros_like(x)
> x = 1 / torch.sqrt(alpha) * (x - ((1 - alpha) / (torch.sqrt(1 - alpha_hat))) * predicted_noise) + torch.sqrt(beta) * noise
> model.train()
> x = (x.clamp(-1, 1) + 1) / 2
> x = (x * 255).type(torch.uint8)
> return x
>
> def train(args):
> setup_logging(args.run_name)
> device = args.device
> dataloader = get_data(args)
> model = UNet_conditional(num_classes=args.num_classes).to(device)
> optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)
> mse = nn.MSELoss()
> diffusion = Diffusion(img_size=args.image_size, device=device)
> logger = SummaryWriter(os.path.join("runs", args.run_name))
> l = len(dataloader)
> ema = EMA(0.995)
> ema_model = copy.deepcopy(model).eval().requires_grad_(False)
>
> for epoch in range(args.epochs):
> logging.info(f"Starting epoch {epoch}:")
> pbar = tqdm(dataloader)
> for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(pbar):
> images = images.to(device)
> labels = labels.to(device)
> t = diffusion.sample_timesteps(images.shape[0]).to(device)
> x_t, noise = diffusion.noise_images(images, t)
> if np.random.random() < 0.1:
> labels = None
> predicted_noise = model(x_t, t, labels)
> loss = mse(noise, predicted_noise)
>
> optimizer.zero_grad()
> loss.backward()
> optimizer.step()
> ema.step_ema(ema_model, model)
>
> pbar.set_postfix(MSE=loss.item())
> logger.add_scalar("MSE", loss.item(), global_step=epoch * 1 + i)
>
> if epoch % 10 == 0:
> labels = torch.arange(10).long().to(device)
> sampled_images = diffusion.sample(model, n=len(labels), labels=labels)
> ema_sampled_images = diffusion.sample(ema_model, n=len(labels), labels=labels)
> plot_images(sampled_images)
> save_images(sampled_images, os.path.join("results", args.run_name, f"{epoch}.jpg"))
> save_images(ema_sampled_images, os.path.join("results", args.run_name, f"{epoch}_ema.jpg"))
> torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join("models", args.run_name, f"ckpt.pt"))
> torch.save(ema_model.state_dict(), os.path.join("models", args.run_name, f"ema_ckpt.pt"))
> torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), os.path.join("models", args.run_name, f"optim.pt"))
>
> def launch():
> import argparse
> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> args = parser.parse_args()
> args.run_name = "DDPM_conditional"
> args.epochs = 500
> args.batch_size = 12
> args.image_size = 64
> args.num_classes = 10
> args.dataset_path = r"C:\Users\suley\Desktop\finetuning\trainingdata"
> args.device = "cuda"
> args.lr = 3e-4
> train(args)
>
> if **name** == '**main**':
> launch()
> device = cuda
> model = UNet_conditional(num_classes=10).to(device)
> ckpt = torch.load("./models/DDPM_conditional/ckpt.pt")
> model.load_state_dict(ckpt)
> diffusion = Diffusion(img_size=64, device=device)
> n = 8
> y = torch.Tensor([6] * n).long().to(device)
> x = diffusion.sample(model, n, y, cfg_scale=0)
> plot_images(x)

I am trying to create a generative AI. Although my training folders and other needed parts seems to work fine I just can not get over this one error.